# zero of order one

Tags: complex-analysis

Let be $f,g$ functions analytic in $z_{0}$, with $z_{0}$ a zero of order one of $g$. 
Show that for small r, we have $$z_{0}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}{\dfrac{zg'(z)}{g(z)}}dz$$

Where $\gamma$ is a circle $|z-z_{0}|=r$, positively oriented.

My attemp.. Is obvius that, if $z_[0]$ is a zero of g, then $$g(z)=(z-z_{0})h(z)$$, where h is analytic and $h(z_{0})\neq 0$, but I don`t know how obtaining equality, pls any idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $z_0$ is a zero of order one then $g(z)$ then you can write

$$ g(z) = (z-z_0)h(z) $$

such that $h(z_0) \neq 0$. Now things will be straightforward.

$$ \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{zg'(z)}{g(z)}dz =  \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{z(h(z)+ (z-z_0)h'(z) )}{(z-z_0)h(z)}dz $$

$$ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{z}{(z-z_0)}dz + \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma} \frac{zh'(z)}{h(z)}dz=z_0+0=z. $$

with a suitable contour $\gamma$ (you can consider $z-z_0=\epsilon e^{i\theta}$).

Comment: Ohh, thanks !! very clear

Comment: The truth is I do not know, sorry XD, I'm very new to the forum